# Handling API error responses with axios (multiple files)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I'm new with React and I was trying to separate my Axios http utilities in different files.

It works fine if I login with correct credentials but when I try wrong credentials and my API responses with a 401 (Bad Credentials) message Axios execute the `then()` method  instead of the `catch()` method.

**axios.ts**

```
import Axios from "axios";

const JSON_CONTENT_TYPE = "application/json";

// axios configuration
const axios = Axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,
  responseType: "json"
});

// ... other requests handlers

export const post = <T = any>(
  url: string,
  body: any,
  params?: any,
  contentType = JSON_CONTENT_TYPE
) => {
  return axios.post<T>(url, body, {
    params,
    headers: { "Content-Type": contentType }
  });
};
```

**login-adapter.ts**

```
import { ILogin } from "../../model/login.model";
import * as Http from "../axios";
import * as StorageManager from "../storage-manager";

type TokenBody = {
  id_token: string;
};

export const login = (credentials: ILogin) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Http.post<TokenBody>("/authenticate", credentials)
      .then((resp) => {
        // Stores jwt in local/session storage.
        // HERE IS WHEN MY APP CRASHES, The error says 'resp is undefined' and THIS ERROR (not the response from my API) is caught by the catch method below.
        StorageManager.setToken(resp.data.id_token, credentials.rememberMe);
        // Does another request to get user info.
        Http.get("/account").then(console.log);
        resolve("Success");
      })
      .catch((error) => reject("Error, " + error.response.data)); // THIS SHOULD SEND THE ERROR MESSAGE TO LoginPage.tsx
  });
};
```

**LoginPage.tsx**

```
import { FormEvent, useState } from "react";
import "../../styles/LoginPage.css";
import * as LoginAdapter from "../../adapters/loginAdapters/login-adapter";
import { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router-dom";

const LoginPage = ({history}: RouteComponentProps) = {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [rememberMe, setRememberMe] = useState(false);

  const submit = (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    LoginAdapter.login({ email, password, rememberMe })
      .then(() => {
        history.push("/admin/courses");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  
  return (
    <form onSubmit={submit}>
      {/* <input ... email, password, and 'remember me' form fields.*/}
    </form>
  );
}

export default LoginPage;
```

When I use **axios** directly from the package. (`import axios from "axios"`) it works perfectly. But I have to rewrite my api endpoint, response type, interceptors, etc. I don't know why it is not working, Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My interceptor was the problem, I didn't notice that the error handler should return a Promise with a reject reason.

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  (resp) => resp,
  (error) => {
  if (
    error.response.status === 401 &&
    error.response.config.url !== "/account"
  ) {
    LoginAdapter.logout();
  }
    // before: <nothing>
    // now:
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```